# Subclassing MKCircle in Swift

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift, mapkit, initializer

I'd like to subclass `MKCircle` (e.g. `MyCircle`) by adding another String property, let's call it "`code`". This property shall not be an optional and constant, so I have to set it from an initializer, right? Of course `MyCircle` should also get center coordinate and the radius. These two properties are read-only, so I also need to set them via initializer.

In the end I need an initializer that takes 3 parameters: `coordinate`, `radius` and `code`. Sounds pretty easy but Swifts designated and convenience initalizers and its rules are giving me a hard time here.

Problem is the definition of `MKCircle`:

```
class MKCircle : MKShape, MKOverlay, MKAnnotation, NSObjectProtocol {

    convenience init(centerCoordinate coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance)

    convenience init(mapRect: MKMapRect) // radius will be determined from MAX(width, height)

    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }
    var radius: CLLocationDistance { get }

    var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect { get }
}
```

As you can see the initializer of `MKCircle` that takes `coordinate` and `radius` is a convenience initalizer and therefore not callable from initializers of my subclass. Also the properties are read-only so I cannot set them from initializers of my subclass or from outside.

I've tried a lot of variations but it seems that the only working way is to make my `code` property an optional, use the inherited convenience initializer to set coordinate and radius and set the code property afterwards, like this:

```
class MyCircle: MKCircle {
    var code: String?
}

overlay = MyCircle(centerCoordinate: coord, radius: radius)
overlay.code = code
```

Did I miss something? Is there a way to define a single convenience initializer that takes 3 arguments in this case?

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This doesn't answer your main question but: MKCircle already has two string properties that it inherits from MKShape: `title` and `subtitle`.

Answer (score 3):

Not much better than your solution, just a wrapper around it:

```
class MyCircle: MKCircle {
    var code: String!

    class func circleAtCenterCoordinate(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance, code: String)->MyCircle {
        let circ=MyCircle(centerCoordinate: coord, radius: radius)
        circ.code=code
        return circ
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
let circ=MyCircle.circleAtCenterCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance, code: String)
```

This can be one of the annoying thing of subclassing Foundation classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCircle: MKCircle {

    private(set) var code: String?

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    static func Instance(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance, code: String?) -> MyCircle {
        let instance = MyCircle(center: center, radius: radius)
        instance.code = code
        return instance
    }
}
```